# select some text in the edittext on drag

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to select some text in the edittext,but I do not know how to do it.

I need such method: when the user touch the screen then drag and off the screen,the text that dragged will be selected.(my English is poor,so do not mind it,thanks)

```
textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textvie1);  
InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(value+0x7f040000);
String string = reader.getString(inputStream);textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
textView.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263384/android-how-to-get-text-position-from-touch-event)

It uses a `onTouchListener` to get the touch position from the motion event to set the cursor to the correct spot and tells to use `ACTION_MOVE` motion event to select text for dragging.

```
mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
          float x = event.getX() + mText.getScrollX();
          int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(0, x);
          if(offset>0)
              if(x>layout.getLineMax(0))
                  mText.setSelection(offset);     // touch was at end of text
              else
                  mText.setSelection(offset - 1);
          break;
          }
      return true;
      }
  };
  mText.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```

Comment: nice answer...is there any other ways

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are trying to do is to select the text in the editText right?
edit your layout and add the following line to the editText

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

from [official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aselectAllOnFocus)

Comment: (My english is poor )I want to select the text in the editText. the text selected by the user casually， when the user touch the screen then drag and off the screen,the text that dragged will be selected