# How to select a text dragging on a Edittext Android? As you do on Notepad,Word etc

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an app with a edittext where I'm using vysor which allows me to control my cell phone from my computer.

What I wanna do is, since I'm on the computer, I want this edittext to work similarly like notepad or word when it comes to select a text, which you normally use your mouse. Because on Android, you have to press and then go right or left to select the text.

Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, AFAIK, the default EditText supports using mouses to select text

Comment: It does, but it has two buttons which you can control the selected part, I can't use mouse to select a text as I do when I'm using notepad or any other windows text editor

Comment: If you have access to the source code, this can be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569783/2925792

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: If dragging to select text is what you meant, you should clarify that in your question so people can understand better. Anyways, if you want to achieve that, you probably need some sort of touch listener to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag selection is possible but not natively, basically, you would have to implement an `OnTouchListener` to the `EditText` yourself and detect the up/down events to see where to start and end selection. Here's a basic example of how something like this would be achieved: (untested, but the idea should be clear)

```
EditText mText = ....
final int[] beginOffset = {-1};
View.OnTouchListener otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE){//only change behavior for mouse
                int i = event.getAction();
                if (i == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
                    float x = event.getX() + mText.getScrollX();
                    float y = event.getY() + mText.getScrollY();
                    int line = layout.getLineForVertical((int) y);                                  
                    int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
                    if (offset > 0) {          
                        if (x > layout.getLineMax(0)){
                            beginOffset[0] = offset;//store beginning offset
                            mText.setSelection(offset); // touch was at end of text
                        }
                        else{
                            beginOffset[0] = offset - 1;//store beginning offset
                            mText.setSelection(offset - 1);
                        }
                    }

                } else if (i == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (beginOffset[0] != -1) {//has previous down action
                        Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
                        float x = event.getX() + mText.getScrollX();
                        float y = event.getY() + mText.getScrollY();  
                        int line = layout.getLineForVertical((int) y);                                            
                        int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
                        if (offset > 0){
                            if (x > layout.getLineMax(0))
                                mText.setSelection(Math.min(offset, beginOffset[0]), Math.max(offset, beginOffset[0])); // touch was at end of text
                            else
                                mText.setSelection(Math.min(offset - 1, beginOffset[0]), Math.max(offset - 1, beginOffset[0]));
                        }
                        beginOffset[0] = 0;//clear beginning offset
                    }
                } else if (i == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) { //selects as mouse moves
                    if (beginOffset[0] != -1) {//has previous down action
                        Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
                        float x = event.getX() + mText.getScrollX();
                        float y = event.getY() + mText.getScrollY();
                        int line = layout.getLineForVertical((int) y);
                        int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
                        if (offset > 0){
                            if (x > layout.getLineMax(0))
                                mText.setSelection(Math.min(offset, beginOffset[0]), Math.max(offset, beginOffset[0])); // touch was at end of text
                            else
                                mText.setSelection(Math.min(offset - 1, beginOffset[0]), Math.max(offset - 1, beginOffset[0]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;//default behavior otherwise
        }
    };
```

Comment: The event is being triggered, but it is not selecting the text when I drag the mouse

Comment: Are you using an actual mouse on a physical device or are you using the remote control software you mentioned? If it's the latter, you probably need to remove the `TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE` check since it's likely the software didn't register its events as MOUSE events

Comment: Oh and also I noticed a typo, the second condition should be `ACTION_UP` not `ACTION_POINTER_UP`, I have fixed it in the answer. Also added multiline selection. Currently the selection should only be selected when you raise the mouse  since it's not checking the `ACTION_MOVE` part, but it should be easy to implement that as well. I have updated the moving part into my answer.

Comment: I'm using the latter as I mentioned (vysor).

Comment: Check if it works now, I fixed a typo and added moving selection

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it didn't work.

When I click, the event it recognizes is MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, ok I changed, but it is giving me an error at section 

if (i == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192134/discussion-between-jackz314-and-joab).

Comment: did you figure out how to deal with the flaws?

Comment: I have removed that "ACTION_MOVE" section, and let the other two, it's almost working right,but first it only shows the selected part when I finish dragging and it's selecting extras texts which I hadn't dragged to

Comment: I didn't see you had updated the answer, it actually worked. thanks bro